# define create button in powershell gui

Tags: powershell

i have written a gui in powershell for creating groups in active directory depending on my selections i have made in the gui.

```
#### Form settings ################################################################
$Form                       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.FormBorderStyle       = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle #modifies the window border
$Form.Text                  = "AD GROUP CREATER"
$Form.Size                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,470)
$Form.StartPosition         = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen
$Form.MinimizeBox           = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox           = $False
$Form.WindowState           = "Normal"
$Form.SizeGripStyle         = "Hide"
$Icon                       = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Join-Path -Path $PSHOME -ChildPath 'powershell.exe'))
$Form.Icon                  = $Icon

#### Label settings #################################################################
$Label           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$Label.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$Label.Text      = "CREATE IN"
$Label.Font      = "8,style=bold"
$Label.Forecolor = "black" 
$Form.Controls.Add($Label) 


#### Group box ########################################################
$groupBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,30)
$groupBox.size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,50)
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)


#### A button ###################################################################
$A= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$A.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,20)
$A.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$A.Text     = "A"
$A.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$A.Add_Click({})
$groupBox.Controls.Add($A)


#### B button ###################################################################
$B= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$B.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$B.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$B.Text     = "B"
$B.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$B.Add_Click({})
$groupBox.Controls.Add($B)


#### Label 2 settings #################################################################
$Label2           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,100)
$Label2.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$Label2.Text      = "GROUP NAME"
$label2.Font = "8, style=bold"
$Label2.Forecolor = "black" 
$Form.Controls.Add($Label2) 


#### textbox settings #################################################################
$Textbox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Textbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,120)
$Textbox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,20)
$Form.Controls.Add($Textbox)


#### Label 3 settings #################################################################
$Label3           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label3.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,170)
$Label3.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(310,20)
$Label3.Text      = "GROUP SECTION"
$Label3.Forecolor = "black" 
$label3.Font = "8, style=bold"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label3) 


#### Group box 2 ########################################################
$groupBox2          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,190)
$groupBox2.size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,160)
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox2)


#### local button ###################################################################
$lokal          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$lokal.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,20)
$lokal.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$lokal.Text     = "Local"
$lokal.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$lokal.Add_Click({})
$groupBox2.Controls.Add($lokal)


#### global button ###################################################################
$global          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$global.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,70)
$global.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$global.Text     = "Global"
$global.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$global.Add_Click({})
$groupBox2.Controls.Add($global)


#### universal button ###################################################################
$universal          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$universal.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,120)
$universal.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$universal.Text     = "Universal"
$universal.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$universal.Add_Click({})
$groupBox2.Controls.Add($universal)


#### Label 4 settings #################################################################
$Label4           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label4.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,170)
$Label4.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,20)
$Label4.Text      = "GROUP TYPE"
$Label4.Forecolor = "black" 
$label4.Font = "8, style=bold"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label4) 


#### Group box 3 ########################################################
$groupBox3          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,190)
$groupBox3.size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,160)
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox3)


#### security button ###################################################################
$security          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$security.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,20)
$security.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$security.Text     = "Security"
$security.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$security.Add_Click({})
$groupBox3.Controls.Add($security)


#### Distribution button ###################################################################
$Distribution          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Distribution.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,70)
$Distribution.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$Distribution.Text     = "Distribution"
$Distribution.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Distribution.Add_Click({})
$groupBox3.Controls.Add($Distribution)


#### Create button ###################################################################
$Create          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Create.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,370)
$Create.Text     = "Create"
$Create.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Create.Width     = 710
$Create.Height    = 50
$Create.Font      = "12,style=bold"
$Create.Add_Click({pinginfo})
$Form.Controls.Add($Create)


$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()

# destroy the form from memory
$Form.Dispose()
```

The gui is finished but i have problems completing my code. what do i need to add to my code that the create button creates the groups? furthermore i think that an assignment to the selection is missing

Comment: Hi you need maak a fuction  after click button take a look this site to addprinter button https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/powershell-gui-howto-get-started/

Comment: on the whole, i am clear about what the logic must look like. i have a problem creating the code with the parametder depending ob the decisions in the gui. how can i hand over the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the now undefined function `pinginfo`, you will need to check what radiobutton is checked in "Create IN" and from that define the `-Path` property for [New-ADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-adgroups).
Then test if a name is filled in, test if this name does not already exist and use that for `-Name`.
The checked radiobutton in "Group Section" decides the parameter `-GroupScope` and the one in "Group Type" is for `-GroupCategory`.

When you have collected those values and tested if they were filled in, create the group.

Something like this perhaps

**Note:** The order in which you test and fill in the Hashtable's properties is not important for splatting purposes.
It's up to you if you want to follow the forms TAB-order or use a different strategy.

```
$Create.Add_Click({
    # create an empty parameters splatting Hashtable for New-ADGroup
    $params = @{Path = $null; Name = $null; GroupScope = $null; GroupCategory = $null}

    # test CREATE IN (OU path)
    if ($A.Checked) { $params.Path = 'TheOU for option A' }
    elseif ($B.Checked) { $params.Path = 'TheOU for option B' }
    else {
        # display an error that there MUST be a choice here
        # I'll leave this as exercise for you
        return
    }

    # test GROUP NAME
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Textbox.Text)) {
        # display an error about the name field being empty
        # I'll leave this as exercise for you
        return
    }
    $params.Name = $Textbox.Text.Trim()

    # test GROUP SECTION (GroupScope)
    if ($DomainLocal.Checked) {$params.GroupScope = 'DomainLocal'}        # as opposed to 'Local' as in the radiobutton's Text
    elseif ($global.Checked) {$params.GroupScope = $global.Text}          # 'Global'
    elseif ($universal.Checked) {$params.GroupScope = $universal.Text}    # 'Universal'
    else {
        # display an error that there MUST be a choice here
        # I'll leave this as exercise for you
        return
    }

    # test GROUP TYPE (GroupCategory)
    if ($security.Checked) {$params.GroupCategory = $security.Text}             # 'Security'
    elseif ($Distribution.Checked) {$params.GroupCategory = $Distribution.Text} # 'Distribution '
    else {
        # display an error that there MUST be a choice here
        # I'll leave this as exercise for you
        return
    }

    # finally check to test if the given groupname already exists
    if (Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq $($params.Name)") {
        # display an error that there already is a group by that name
        return
    }

    # next create the group
    New-ADGroup @params
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i will have a look. your code says Closing ")" is missing after an expression in the "if" statement. but i can't figure out where it's missing

Comment: @chkdsk Yep, you're right. I forgot a closing bracket on the test for `$params.Name`. Fixed now

Comment: i implement your code to mine and i fill out the gui and press the create button, the scripts need an input for the groupscope. the checkbox was marked `Get-ADGroup : Error analyzing the query: "Name -eq TEST-GROUP" Error message: "syntax error" at the following position: "10".`

Comment: and `New-ADGroup : The "GroupScope" parameter cannot be bound. The value "security" cannot be converted to the type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroupScope". Error: "The identifier "security" cannot be assigned to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following 
enumerator names and repeat the operation:`

Comment: @chkfsk Sorry, I've mixed up `GroupScope` and `GroupCategory`.

Comment: @chkdsk P.S. The .Text property for the $lokal checkbox should be `"DomainLocal"`, not `"Local"` (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-adgroup), parameter `-GroupScope`

Comment: i think i need to change the order in the param part isn't it beacuse the syntax isn't wrong?

Comment: @chkdsk Please see my edited answer. `$params` is now a Hashtable as it should be. I have also added more inline comments for you

Answer (score 0):

@Theo please have a look. I still need to input a GroupScope. After thet, the script says it is a wrong name but my name looks like test-group

```
#### Form settings ################################################################
$Form                       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.FormBorderStyle       = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle #modifies the window border
$Form.Text                  = "AD GROUP CREATER"
$Form.Size                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,470)
$Form.StartPosition         = "CenterScreen" #loads the window in the center of the screen
$Form.MinimizeBox           = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox           = $False
$Form.WindowState           = "Normal"
$Form.SizeGripStyle         = "Hide"
$Icon                       = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((Join-Path -Path $PSHOME -ChildPath 'powershell.exe'))
$Form.Icon                  = $Icon

#### Label settings #################################################################
$Label           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$Label.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$Label.Text      = "CREATE IN"
$Label.Font      = "8,style=bold"
$Label.Forecolor = "black" 
$Form.Controls.Add($Label) 


#### Group box ########################################################
$groupBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,30)
$groupBox.size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,50)
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)


#### A button ###################################################################
$A= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$A.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,20)
$A.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$A.Text     = "A"
$A.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$A.Add_Click({})
$groupBox.Controls.Add($A)


#### B button ###################################################################
$B= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$B.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$B.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$B.Text     = "B"
$B.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$B.Add_Click({})
$groupBox.Controls.Add($B)


#### Label 2 settings #################################################################
$Label2           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,100)
$Label2.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$Label2.Text      = "GROUP NAME"
$label2.Font = "8, style=bold"
$Label2.Forecolor = "black" 
$Form.Controls.Add($Label2) 


#### textbox settings #################################################################
$Textbox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$Textbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,120)
$Textbox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,20)
$Form.Controls.Add($Textbox)


#### Label 3 settings #################################################################
$Label3           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label3.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,170)
$Label3.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(310,20)
$Label3.Text      = "GROUP SECTION"
$Label3.Forecolor = "black" 
$label3.Font = "8, style=bold"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label3) 


#### Group box 2 ########################################################
$groupBox2          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,190)
$groupBox2.size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,160)
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox2)


#### local button ###################################################################
$DomainLocal          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$DomainLocal.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,20)
$DomainLocal.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$DomainLocal.Text     = "Local"
$DomainLocal.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$DomainLocal.Add_Click({})
$groupBox2.Controls.Add($DomainLocal)


#### global button ###################################################################
$global          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$global.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,70)
$global.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$global.Text     = "Global"
$global.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$global.Add_Click({})
$groupBox2.Controls.Add($global)


#### universal button ###################################################################
$universal          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$universal.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,120)
$universal.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$universal.Text     = "Universal"
$universal.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$universal.Add_Click({})
$groupBox2.Controls.Add($universal)


#### Label 4 settings #################################################################
$Label4           = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label4.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,170)
$Label4.Size      = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,20)
$Label4.Text      = "GROUP TYPE"
$Label4.Forecolor = "black" 
$label4.Font = "8, style=bold"
$Form.Controls.Add($Label4) 


#### Group box 3 ########################################################
$groupBox3          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,190)
$groupBox3.size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,160)
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox3)


#### security button ###################################################################
$security          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$security.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,20)
$security.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$security.Text     = "Security"
$security.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$security.Add_Click({})
$groupBox3.Controls.Add($security)


#### Distribution button ###################################################################
$Distribution          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Distribution.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,70)
$Distribution.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$Distribution.Text     = "Distribution"
$Distribution.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Distribution.Add_Click({})
$groupBox3.Controls.Add($Distribution)


#### Create button ###################################################################
$Create          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Create.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,370)
$Create.Text     = "Create"
$Create.Cursor   = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$Create.Width     = 710
$Create.Height    = 50
$Create.Font      = "12,style=bold"
$Create.Add_Click({
    # create an empty parameters object for New-ADGroup
    $params = '' | Select-Object Name, GroupScope, GroupCategory, Path

     $params.Name = $Textbox.Text.Trim()
    # test if there is a name given and if so, test if that name does not already exist in AD
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($params.Name) -or (Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq $($params.Name)")) {
        # display an error about the name field
        # I'll leave this as exercise for you
        return
    }

    if ($DomainLocal.Checked) {$params.GroupScope = $DomainLocal.Text}
    elseif ($global.Checked) {$params.GroupScope = $global.Text}
    elseif ($universal.Checked) {$params.GroupScope = $universal.Text}
    else {
        # display an error that there MUST be a choice here
        # I'll leave this as exercise for you
        return
    }

    if ($security.Checked) {$params.GroupCategory = $security.Text}
    elseif ($Distribution.Checked) {$params.GroupCategory = $Distribution.Text}
    else {
        # display an error that there MUST be a choice here
        # I'll leave this as exercise for you
        return
    }

    if ($A.Checked) { $params.Path = 'TheOU for option A' }
    elseif( $B.Checked) { $params.Path = 'TheOU for option B' }
    else {
        # display an error that there MUST be a choice here
        # I'll leave this as exercise for you
        return
    }    

    

    # next create the group
    New-ADGroup @params
})
$Form.Controls.Add($Create)


$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()

# destroy the form from memory
$Form.Dispose()
```